# Adding blocks in admin issue

Tags: module, blocks, xml

I want to add tabs and fields. But somehow it does not display anything, just the header and footer of the magento admin. What should I do ? Thx 
This is the structure of my module :

[image]

**This is the content of etc/adminhtml.xml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <attributegrouping translate="title" module="attributegrouping">
            <title>Attribute Grouping</title>
            <sort_order>90</sort_order> 
            <children>
                <form translate="title" module="attributegrouping">
                    <title>Add new group</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/addgroup/index/</action>
                </form>
            </children>
        </attributegrouping>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <netgroup>
                        <title>Netgroup</title>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <form>
                                <title>Add new group</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </form>
                        </children>
                    </netgroup>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**This is the content of etc/config.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Netgroup_Attributegrouping>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <attributegrouping>
                <class>Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Block</class>
            </attributegrouping>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
            <attributegrouping>
                <class>Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Helper</class>
            </attributegrouping>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <netgroup_attributegrouping after="Mage_Adminhtml">Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Adminhtml</netgroup_attributegrouping>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <netgroup_attributegrouping>
                    <file>netgroup_attributegrouping.xml</file>
                </netgroup_attributegrouping>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**This is the controllers/Adminhtml/AddgroupController.php content:**

```
<?php

class Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Adminhtml_AddgroupController extends 

Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
        public function indexAction() 
        {
                $this->loadLayout();
                $this->renderLayout();
        }

}
```

**This is the content of Block/Adminhtml/Form/Edit/Tabs.php:**

```
<?php

class Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('edit_home_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__('Form Tabs'));
    }
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTab('general', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__('General'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__('General'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_general')->toHtml(),
        ));

        $product_content = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab_product', 'adminform_products.grid')->toHtml();
        $serialize_block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer');
        $serialize_block->initSerializerBlock('adminform_products.grid', 'getSelectedProducts', 'products', 'selected_products');
        $serialize_block->addColumnInputName('position');
        $product_content .= $serialize_block->toHtml();
        $this->addTab('associated_products', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__('Products'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('netgroup_attributegrouping')->__('Products'),
            'content'   => $product_content
        ));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

}
```

**And the content of the netgroup_attributegrouping.xml from the layout(design/default/default/layout) is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">

    <attributegrouping_index>
        <update handle="editor"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit" name="attributegrouping"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tabs" name="attributegrouping_tabs"/>
        </reference>
    </attributegrouping_index>

</layout>
```

This is what i got :[image]

Comment: any ideea what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `netgroup_attributegrouping before="Mage_Adminhtml"`? I think the fields need to be added before the Mage_Adminhtml renders the whole thing. At least that's how my modules are configured.

p.s. lacking the reputation to comment, this became and answer instead.

Edit:
Add the acl in the adminhtml.xml under the `<menu>` tag like this:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <attributegrouping translate="title" module="attributegrouping">
                    <title>Attribute Grouping</title>
                        <children>
                            <new_group translate="title">
                                <title>Add new group</title>
                            </new_group>
                        </children>
                    </attributegrouping>
                </children>
            </admin>
        <resources>
    </acl>
```

It follows the same structure as your menu, and the titles you enter are the titles you see in the backends user rights management. You can also set a sort order to order these in the rights management list.

Edit 3: 
You can try to add your block programmatically to check whether your layout is malconfigured and which block path indeed works:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('{block-handle as in config.xml}/{block's path relative to Block-folder}');
$this->renderLayout();
```

Edit 4:

```
<?php 
class Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{}
```

this needs to go into Netgroup/Attributegrouping/Helper/Data.php

Comment: I tried before, after and still im getting nothing. if i write echo 1; exit(); in the Tabs.php , also im getting nothing. It does not reach the class from the Tabs.php. Smth somewhere my xml does not work and I dont know why. Any other ideea? thx for helping me :)

Comment: Do you set your ACL somewhere? You need to manage permissions to view your custom menus.

Comment: nope. how can i do that ?

Comment: check my post again and see the acl, but i still get nothing, blank page

Comment: now i the item from the main menu just disapperead

Comment: I edited my answer, try putting the module tag in your acl. Also with xml it can be any small thing, make sure there are no typos in the tags and so on. In your `<action>` tag, try the path `adminhtml/addgroup/index` without the `/` at the end

Comment: can you update your post and show me the all content of adminhtml.xml how should it be ?

Comment: Yeah, I added something from one of my working modules

Comment: ok, but do you really think that the acl is the cause the problem ?

Comment: Well, if you don't have it, it definitely is the cause of 'some' problems ;) But it is frustratingly easy to misconfigure xml files, I probably spent more time on getting the xml right than I spent on coding the blocks and models themselves.

Comment: ok i update my code with yours, but still the same :(. I think, but im not an expert that the problem is from the netgroup_attributegrouping.xml from the layout. Because there im calling the class: netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tabs. And is seems that does not reach in the that class.

Comment: Your menu items are displayed? And when you click the item it redirects you to an empty Magento page? What is the url of that Magento page? Is your router working correctly?

Comment: I updated my post. see the image at the end. There you get the url

Comment: The router seems to work ok. I added a code snippet with which you can add a block directly from the index action, this way you can figure out if your layout.xml is malconfigured and which block path works.

Comment: i tried like this: $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('netgroup_attributegrouping_block_adminhtml_form_edit_tab'));

Comment: can i send you the files via email ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am at work here with no way to test project unrelated code :/

Comment: try `createBlock('attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab')` the part before `/` is the blocks handle from your config.xml, the part behidn `/` is the path of the block relative to the modules block folder. which probably is the mistake in your layout.xml after all.

Comment: still without any result :|

Comment: have to me something else, what are  we missing ?

Comment: Look at your folder structure. Your Tabs.php is in a Tab folder where it should be in the Edit folder?

Comment: Tabs.php is in Adminhtml/Form/Edit, the path is correct

Comment: I change this: $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tab')); in this :$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tabs'));, there is a missing "s"

Comment: now i getting an error message: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Netgroup_Attributegrouping_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dachim\app\Mage.php on line 546

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. You defined a helper path in the config, you need to actually put a helper class up there.

Comment: Edited a Helper class up into my answer. The Helper class can be completely empty, it just needs to be there.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">

    <adminhtml_addgroup_index>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="netgroup_attributegrouping/adminhtml_form_edit_tabs" name="adminform_tabs"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_addgroup_index>

</layout>

Comment: that is the solution, finally, thx for help